# Why do I have to start some scripts with "npm start x" and others with "npm x" only?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

In my *package.json*, I have the following part for script definition.

```
"scripts": {
 "ng": "ng",
 "start": "ng serve",
 "build": "ng build --prod",
 "test": "ng test",
 "lint": "ng lint",
 "e2e": "ng e2e"
}, ...
```

Whenever I want to run the app, I go *npm start* (which executes *ng serve*). I can also go *npm **run** start* achieving the same result. Now, when I tried to build my app, I went *npm build* but contrary to my expectation, there was no build being executed (no error, neither, just nothing output to the console when the execution completed). I had to go *npm run build* instead (which executed *ng build --prod*, of course).

I don't understand the discrepancy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`npm start` and `npm test` are special values you can run without ... Well without using the word `run`.

`npm run` is actually a shortcut of `npm run-script`, which allows you to run scripts you wrote into the `scripts` property of your `package.json`.

But `npm run` can also run scripts that are located into the `node_modules/.bin` folder.

This means you can run `npm run mocha` instead of `mocha test`, for instance.

Otherwise, npm is an executable that you can use with `npm [command]`.

**EDIT** In case you wonder, `start` and `test` are specific and don't need the run keyword because they're the most used ones, and using them allow you to run long commands very quickly.

Isn't it nice to launch

```
npm test
```

instead of

```
ng test --code-coverage --reporters mocha,progress,jkhtml --browsers chrome,phantomjs -sm=false
```

???

Comment: I see. The automagic that's supposed to help. But I wonder what is happening when I go *npm build*. Since there's no *run*, the script doesn't get executed but what is being executed?!

Comment: Well, I would say nothing, but you can probably install a package called build with `npm i -g build`, and that should launch the said package. By the way, I edited my answer, feel free to look !

Comment: I did. +1 and acc to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can run npm "native" scripts directly, for custom scripts, you have to `npm run {customscript}`

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts