# DOCKERFILE NPM Command to include colon and hyphens

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, dockerfile

My package.json have these scripts:
[image]

How do I change the CMD array to fit that criteria for "start:stage-ena-sso"?
I tried this but it cant compile:

```
CMD ["npm","start:stage-ena-sso"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use it in the following way

```
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:stage-ena-sso"]
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but why is it for the case of "start", we do not need the "run" keyword?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207345/why-do-i-have-to-start-some-scripts-with-npm-start-x-and-others-with-npm-x-o#:~:text=Otherwise%2C%20npm%20is%20an%20executable,run%20long%20commands%20very%20quickly.